# Scroll Content while dragging gridstack card

Tags: scroll, drag, gridstack

I am using gridstack to show my widgets. Dragging and resizing works fine for gridstack cards, but when I drag card to bottom, container of the cards does not scrolls. I want to scroll that container when I am dragging card. That container is simply a div element and all cards are added in that container.(I am working in backbone and using underscore, jQuery and gridstack.)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You only have to go to gridstack.js and switch that value to "true", and it will scroll automatic.